# How to pass an Angular JSON object into jQuery code

Tags: jquery, angular

I'm trying to pass a JSON object made by Angular5 into jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "api/loginservice",
  type: "POST",
  data: formData,
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  },
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.user))
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log('error login');
  }
});
```

`this.user` is an angular JSONobject, but jQuery gives an error, that `this.user is undefined`.

Comment: Cache `this.user` outside `$.ajax()` and then use it

Answer (score 0):

Change `function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){}` to  `(data, textStatus, jqXHR) =>{}`

Please **[read](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/features/arrow_functions.html)** this also

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This:-

var _self = this;
  $.ajax({
  url: "api/loginservice",
  type: "POST",
  data: formData,
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  },
  success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(_self.user))
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log('error login');
  }
});
```